# The remote server returned an error: (502) Bad Gateway while bypassing proxy

Tags: vb.net, sockets, vb.net-2010

I am trying to bypass proxy using below code... But it is showing me error i.e. ("The remote server returned an error: (502) Bad Gateway."). In inner exception i found error ("The proxy could not connect to the destination in time"). I searched a lot on internet but didnt get solution.
Here's my code for bypassing proxy...

```
 Function ConnectViaHTTPProxy() As TcpClient
    Dim SOCKET1 As System.Net.Sockets.Socket
    Try
        Dim request As HttpWebRequest = WebRequest.Create("Web Address--10.10.10.10") 
        Dim cred As String = "ProxyServer:Port--http://10.10.10.10:1010/"

        Dim webProxy = New WebProxy(cred)

        request.UseDefaultCredentials = True
        request.Proxy = webProxy
        request.Timeout = 3600 * 1000
        request.ReadWriteTimeout = 3600 * 1000

        request.Method = "CONNECT"

        Dim credentials = New NetworkCredential("UserName", "Password", "Domain_Name")
        webProxy.Credentials = credentials
        Dim response = request.GetResponse()
        Dim responseStream = response.GetResponseStream()

        Debug.Assert(responseStream IsNot Nothing)
        Const Flags As BindingFlags = BindingFlags.NonPublic Or BindingFlags.Instance
        Dim rsType = responseStream.[GetType]()
        Dim connectionProperty = rsType.GetProperty("Connection", Flags)
        Dim connection = connectionProperty.GetValue(responseStream, Nothing)
        Dim connectionType = connection.[GetType]()
        Dim networkStreamProperty = connectionType.GetProperty("NetworkStream", Flags)
        Dim networkStream = networkStreamProperty.GetValue(connection, Nothing)
        Dim nsType = networkStream.[GetType]()
        Dim socketProperty = nsType.GetProperty("Socket", Flags)
        Dim socket = DirectCast(socketProperty.GetValue(networkStream, Nothing), Socket)

        SOCKET1 = socket
        SOCKET1.ReceiveTimeout = 0
        SOCKET1.SendTimeout = 0

        Return (New TcpClient() With {.Client = SOCKET1})            
    Catch ex As WebException
        If ex.Status = WebExceptionStatus.ProtocolError Then
            Dim resp As WebResponse = ex.Response
            Using sr As New StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream())
                FileWrite(lERROR, sr.ReadToEnd().ToString(), 0)
            End Using
        End If
        'FileWrite(lERROR, ex.InnerException.ToString(), 0)
    End Try

End Function
```

Can you please tell me where i am wrong....

Comment: Guys... Any help on this?